# Ubercart uc_recurring subscription issue

Tags: ubercart

I'm using [uc_recurring](http://drupal.org/project/uc_recurring) module in my Drupal based site. I just can't get on with it:
In the cart I want to make possible of subscribing for the products. The customer can subscribe for the products (weekly, biweekly, monthly, semianually, etc) while buying them, for he can get discounts through subscription(12%, 9%, 6%, 3%) respectively. As far as the customer is subscribed for some type of products, on that point when the appointed day comes, transaction should occur via PayPal gateway and a certain amount of money needs to be charged from the subscriber's account, and send them notifications.

How can I manage subscription and unsubscription?